# MySQL Update table with sum value of another table

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a query that I can't seem to manipulate to work in a SUM function in MySQL:

Here is what I want:

> UPDATE account_seeds AS a 
>   INNER JOIN b AS b ON b.accountID = a.accountID AND a.areaID = b.areaID
>   INNER JOIN b_seed AS s ON s.buildingID = b.buildingID
>   INNER JOIN seed_class AS c ON c.seedID = s.seedID
>   SET a.amount = a.amount + ***SUM(s.amount)***
>   WHERE b.status='active' AND a.seedID = s.seedID

Now it obviously won't let me use the SUM in the update without separating it.  I have tried joining select queries but can't quite get my head around it.  The basic premise being that I have multiple buildings(rows) that has a seed value that will increase total seeds of that type in the area for a particular account.  Without the sum it only updates one of the buildings that has a matching seed value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
    account_seeds AS a 
  INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT b.accountID, b.areaID, s.seedID
           , SUM(s.amount) AS add_on 
      FROM b AS b 
        INNER JOIN b_seed AS s 
          ON s.buildingID = b.buildingID
        INNER JOIN seed_class AS c 
          ON c.seedID = s.seedID
      WHERE b.status = 'active' 
      GROUP BY b.accountID, b.areaID, s.seedID
    ) AS g
    ON  g.accountID = a.accountID 
    AND g.areaID = a.areaID
    AND g.seedID = a.seedID
SET 
    a.amount = a.amount + g.add_on ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a nested query:

```
UPDATE account_seeds AS a 
INNER JOIN b AS b ON b.accountID = a.accountID AND a.areaID = b.areaID
INNER JOIN b_seed AS s ON s.buildingID = b.buildingID
INNER JOIN seed_class AS c ON c.seedID = s.seedID
SET a.amount = a.amount + (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM b_seed)
WHERE b.status='active' AND a.seedID = s.seedID
```

Can you try that?